# org-capture template does not replace the date placeholder or use the correct level

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-capture

I'm trying to create an org capture template that will just insert a second level point: `"** 2021/07/16"` (or whatever the current date is).

I expect this setq example to do that:

```
  (setq org-capture-templates
                '(
                  ("d" "Daily" entry (file "~/notes/daily.org") "** %Y/%m/%d %?")))
```

However what it inserts instead is:

```
* %Y/%m/%d
```

(first level point instead of second level, and the literal %Y etc instead of the date)

This is based on (probably a poor) reading of org-capture examples with slight adjustment. I have at most a basic understanding of org mode and emacs so please feel free to explain any principles that I've missed.

I'm also using spacemacs, in case that is relevant. This `setq` command is inside my `defun dotspacemacs/user-config`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org-capture-templates` probably has the densest doc-string of any variable. The way I deal with it is figure out what I need to do, do it once and then *never* change it :-) The downside is that when I need to change it, I find that I've forgotten everything so I need to start from scratch. But after doing it a dozen times or so, the relearning gets faster and easier. In short, hang in there!

For the time stamp, you can either use `%t` which provides the date in ISO format, or you can use `%<%Y/%m/%d>` as the doc string of `org-capture-templates` describes:

> %<...>      The result of format-time-string on the ... format specification.

The level at which the capture is entered for an `entry` type is again described in the doc string:

> ... Will be filed as the child of the target entry or as a top-level entry.

Since you are not using a target entry, it is filed as a top-level entry, no matter how many stars you put in the template. See the `target` description in the doc string.

You could create a top-level headline, say `* My daily thoughts` in your file and then use

```
  ... (file+headline "~/notes/daily.org" "My daily thoughts") ...
```

instead of the plain `file` entry: the captures would end up under that headline.

There is plenty more in the doc string to keep you busy for a while. Start simple, experiment, ask questions: you'll get there.

BTW, to get the doc string of the variable, do

```
C-h v org-capture-templates
```

and if you don't know yet how to use the emacs help system, do `C-h ?` and learn how to use it ASAP!